# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in functional component while it works in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title says I have an error that says "cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when I'm handling change in `FormInput`. However, if I refactor my `SignUp` component from functional to class component everything magically works. Is there anything I do wrong in the functional component while using useState or what's the deal? I have attached a code of components that are involved in this issue. In details `otherProps.value.length` inside `FormInput` triggers an error upon `handleChange`helper function call.

Functional component:

```
function SignUp() {
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = newUser;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );
      await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });
      setNewUser({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setNewUser({ [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h2 className="title">I do not have a account</h2>
      <span>Sign up wit your email and password</span>
      <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="displayName"
          value={newUser.displayName}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="Display Name"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={newUser.email}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="Email"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={newUser.password}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="Password"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="confirmPassword"
          value={newUser.confirmPassword}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          label="Confirm Password"
          required
        />
        <CustomButton type="submit">Sign up</CustomButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Class component:

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      displayName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      confirmPassword: "",
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;

    e.preventDefault();

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email,
        password
      );
      await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });
      this.setState({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
  render() {
    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="sign-up">
        <h2 className="title">I do not have a account</h2>
        <span>Sign up wit your email and password</span>
        <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <FormInput
            type="text"
            name="displayName"
            value={displayName}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Display Name"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Email"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Password"
            required
          />
          <FormInput
            type="password"
            name="confirmPassword"
            value={confirmPassword}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
            label="Confirm Password"
            required
          />
          <CustomButton type="submit">Sign up</CustomButton>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

FormInput:

```
function FormInput({ handleChange, label, ...otherProps }) {
  return (
    <div className="group">
      <input className="form-input" onChange={handleChange} {...otherProps} />
      {label ? (
        <label
          className={`${otherProps.value.length ? "shrink" : ""
          } form-input-label`}
        >
          {label}
        </label>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you console.log otherProps in FormInput, could it be that you are missing that property for one of them

Comment: Specifically: _"Unlike the `setState` method found in class components, `useState` does not automatically merge update objects."_

Comment: And the bugfix being: `setNewUser(userState => ({ ...userState, [name]: value }));`